# try convert string to decimal

Tags: c#, uwp

The code below does not work.
1)It is not converting in try function double liczbaa=Convert.ToDouble(a)
but it does not doing it
and its skipping to exception and then program breaks.
1)It doesnt show format exception "bad values" in trzyde_wynik.Text

```
namespace Kubik
{
public sealed partial class TrzyDe : Page
{
    public TrzyDe()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void wylicz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string a, b, c;
        a = wpis_a.ToString();
        b = wpis_b.ToString();
        c = wpis_c.ToString();

        try
        {
            double liczba1 = Convert.ToDouble(a);
            double liczba2 = Convert.ToDouble(b);
            double liczba3 = Convert.ToDouble(c);

        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            trzyde_wynik.Text = "bad values";

        }
        double liczbaa = Convert.ToDouble(a);
        double liczbab = Convert.ToDouble(b);
        double liczbac = Convert.ToDouble(c);
        double trzyde_w = (liczbaa * liczbab * liczbac) / 1000000;
        trzyde_wynik.Text = Convert.ToString(trzyde_w);

     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: What's in `wpis_a`...?

Comment: Well, the code after the catch repeats the error. Why do you expect this to be different from the code inside the try/catch?

Comment: What is the exception? Have you checked that wpis_a/wpis_b/wpis_c aren't null?

Comment: In any case, you don't want to handle this kind of exception. The answer is always the same: use TryParse instead. There are thousands of duplicates for this. Just a little search effort needed.

Comment: As @Steve said, you probably want to "return" after handling the exception

Comment: @Pikoh: a = wpis_a.ToString(); should be a = wpis_a.Text.ToString(); it is working but whe i put in textbox "wpis_a" 1, wpis_b=1, wpis_c=1 i get  trzyde_wynik.Text 1E-06. To small field?

Comment: 1E-06 is 0.000001, which is exactly what you  get when calculating 1^3 **/1000000** as you do...

Comment: Please be a little more specific as to what exactly you want to achieve. Looks to me like a unit conversion like liters to cubic meters perhaps? What units do you expect to be entered in the textboxes and what unit should the result be?

Comment: i want entering in wpis_a, wpis_b, wpis_c boxes unit in cm but with 2 places after dot.1,2cm 1,25. And (100cm x 100cm x 10cm)/1000000 should me give 0,1m

Comment: @LocEngineer i checked, when I write 100,100, 10 it is working ok. Problem is when I insert 1,1,1 and get 1E-06 how You said because it is 0,0000001 , how to fix it?  when i put (5 5 5)/1000000=0,000125, when i put (4,5 4,5 4,5)/1000000=0,091125 but it is not ok, its like (45 45 45)/1000000= the same 0,091125. Problem is ","  , dot "." is working how to fix to , and . be ok

Comment: I see. Amended my answer using culture. Polish is the choice here if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @LocEngineer, sorry for my english, i dont understand everyting, translators not works good with polish language. And yes, its unit coversion app. Make cm x cm x cm to cube meters, thats why i /1000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are obviously three issues here:

1. Properly interpreting the text box values as double
2. Respecting the culture-specific decimal separator
3. Returning the result with decimal separator instead of scientific notation

Based on this, the following should get you going. Please note the usage of double.TryParse() and ToString("F6") which formats the result as floating point number with 6 decimals behind the separator:

```
private void wylicz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string a, b, c;

    var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL");
    var style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number;
    a = wpis_a.Text;
    b = wpis_b.Text;
    c = wpis_c.Text;

    double liczba1 = 0.0;
    double liczba2 = 0.0;
    double liczba3 = 0.0;

    if (!(double.TryParse(a, style, culture, out liczba1) && double.TryParse(b, style, culture, out liczba2) && double.TryParse(c, style, culture, out liczba3)))
    {
        trzyde_wynik.Text = "bad values";
    }
    else
    {
        double trzyde_w = (liczba1 * liczba2 * liczba3) / 1000000;
        trzyde_wynik.Text = trzyde_w.ToString("F6", culture);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have problem with culture info, there is no CreateSpecificCulture option. I have only CurrentCulture, CurrentUICulture

Comment: Add a reference to System.Globalization

Comment: I added, var style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number; working, no error. I tried var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture("pl-PL"); but there is somewhere error in definition

Comment: Not `.CurrentCulture(` but `.CreateSpecificCulture(`.

Comment: there is no .CreateSpecificCulture. i'm to big amator, i dont no how it works but var style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number; works fine. I dont get E.... results. Thank You very much. Thaks for the patience. I thik it is ok

Comment: I've created a quick Winforms application and tested this. Works just fine. I have amended the culture and style part so you can use it directly as pasted here.

Comment: maybe is difference between winforms and UWP

Comment: Make sure you have a reference set to `System` and you are `using System;`

Comment: I'm using system. Visualstudio recognize var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo. After dot i dont have CreateSpecificCulture. VS showing error. Maybe I should not use culture, better maybe changing . to ,    ?or changing .,;: to symbol setted in control panel as separator?

Comment: The error in VS is :'Cultureinfo' does not contain a definition for 'CreatespecificCulture'

Comment: Dang. Must be UWP-related. Try `var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1045);` instead.

Comment: There is no getcultureinfo. I have only options: currentculture, currentuiculture, defaultthreadcurrentculture, defaultthreadcurrentUIculture,Equals, InvariatnCulture,Readonly,Referenceequals

Comment: Sounds like Globalization has not been given much thought in UWP. :-( Can you try with this nuget package for `System.Globalization.Extensions`? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Globalization.Extensions/